# How to use the name of the current database to delete it?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I try to assign "DATABASE()" which returns the name of the current database to a variable "@mydb" and to use it back to drop this database.

```
SET @mydb = DATABASE();
DROP DATABASE @mydb;
```

And i got this error `ER_PARSE_ERROR near @mydb`

Comment: You would need to use dynamic sql please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As P.Salmon mentioned you have to use [Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html):

```
SET @mydb = DATABASE();
SET @sql = CONCAT('DROP DATABASE ', @mydb);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM  @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Comment: And that must be in a Stored Procedure.  And you may need to do a `use` to get out of the directory before doing the `EXECUTE`.